# All sinon stubs fail after nock intercept

Tags: javascript, sinon, chai, nock

Im running unit tests against a software application. Within the specific part of the application I have some async functions, followed by an http request, followed by more async functions. I am working on just stubbing everything out with sinon to test the code within this function.  The first few functions that are hit are stubbed out correctly. The http request is intercepted by my nock and then all ensuing sinon stubs fail and the functions try to execute.

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
const nock = require('nock');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

const ExternalClass = require('ExternalClass');
const ExternalClass2 = require('ExternalClass2');
const TestClass = require('TestClass');

describe('Test a Class',()=>{
    beforeEach(()=> {
        sandbox.stub(ExternalClass, 'extFunction').returns('');
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        sandbox.restore();
        nock.cleanAll();
    });

    describe('Test Specific Function ', () => {
        it('Successfully executes', ()=> {
        nock('http://localhost:8989/api/')
            .get('/something')
            .reply(200, {name: 'thething', id:'1234'});

        sandbox.stub(ExternalClass2, 'ext2function')
            .returns({name: 'theotherthing', id:'4567'});
        TestClass.testfunction().then(res => {
            expect(res).to.be.an('object');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This code is testing against the following
------->

```
const testfunction = async(){
  await extFunction();  //executes correctly according to the stub
  let options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:8989/api/something',
    method: 'GET',
    json: true
  };
  await rp(options);  //executes and is correctly intercepted by nock
  await ext2function(); //doesnt execute correctly according to the stub
}
```

Also:
if I add the await ext2function above the request promise function it then executes correctly according to the sinon stub. 
Also as a headsup this is just an example of my code, so hopefully these no syntax issues haha.

Comment: I am thinking that you might be missing an `await` on `rp(options)` also which library instance is `rp`?

Comment: Oops. I mocked up an example of my problem there should be an await there. With it though the problem still persists.  And rp is request-promise. Its an http request client.

Comment: maybe because rp is based on bluebird. Have you considered to try with request-promise-native?